# Java - Stuck in "for" loop

Tags: java

I am writing a java program that takes a number, x,  as input from the user, sums all numbers from 1 to x (including x) that are divisible by 3, and displays the sum. it compiles without error but when I execute the program, it gets stuck in the loop and continues executing until I close the command prompt. I think the problem is inside the parenthesis after "for". I tried replacing the commands inside the loop with a simple

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

and I got hundreds of Hello's streaming down the command prompt window. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");

    int x = keyboard.nextInt();
    int i, total = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <= x; i=+3)
    {
        total =+ i;
    }

    System.out.println("The sum is " + total);
}
```

Comment: `i=+3` just means `i = 3`, you see the problem with that, right?

Comment: if this is the code you use, =+ is not a thing. Try +=. For the code you've written, i will always equal 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `=+` should be `+=`.

`total =+ i;` is the same as `total = +i;` which is the same as `total = i;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment is wrong. At the time being, you are simply assigning the counter to 3.

```
i += 3
```

You've done the same with your total variable as well. You can fix it in the same way:

```
total += i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong operator it is endlees loop. Use += **not =+**

```
i += 3
```

Answer (score 0):

just fix when you increase the i and the total. Here is the class to compile and run :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class keyboard {
public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");

        int x = keyboard.nextInt();
        int i, total = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= x; i+=3)
        {
            total += i;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is " + total);

    }
}
```